# Is it possible to switch from front to rear camera during an AR session with AR Foundation in Unity for an android build?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, mobile, arcore

I am developing an AR app on the Google pixel 7 where I need to use a gesture as input from the front camera to cause an interaction in the AR space rendered through the rear camera. To my knowledge there is no way to do this simultaneously possibly due to the single image processor on the Pixel 7 (but if I am wrong please let me know ).

To try and circumvent this issue, I am thinking about inputting a gesture with the front camera and switching to the rear camera quickly afterwards to toggle changes in the AR space rendered in the rear camera. I am trying to achieve this with minimal lag.

I am developing on the Unity platform using ARFoundation and ARCore (android). So far I have tinkered around for hours in the past few days with the "AR Camera Manager Scripts" (see image) which allow you to set the camera to the front or rear camera before runtime,but I'd like a method of doing this quickly with minimal latency during runtime. Has anyone every done this before?

[image]